# Commerce Kickstart 2 Collection - Displaying too much information

Tags: commerce

I'm having an issue, for some reason, the collection page is displaying the product detail, included with the add to cart. Where would I adjust this setting? I was comparing with another product variation, and can't seem to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally fix this. I fixed this issue by going into Content Types, and just adjusted the Manage Display setting under Product List.